# Selenium chrome can't move focus from url

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I got this problem on Chrome driver, where URL stays focused, I have a scenario where I can't use input send value because the value entering is handled differently on the website and not through input. So I have to go click the div for another div to be focusable and use `SendKeys.SendWait` to send a text through the keyboard.

When I tried Firefox driver it worked, but it's slower. When SendKeys.SendWait is executed on Chrome driver it sends the text to the URL and not to the div that is focusable and is waiting for the keyboard.